# How can I upload or delete files to multi-ftp servers

Tags: ftp

Is there a program for upload or delete files to multi-ftp servers.

eg.

```
Ftp sites:
  ftp.a-site.com
  ftp.another-site.com

Command:
  DELETE a-file From All FTP SITES
Or:
  DELETE a-file or selected-file From all-selected-sites
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scriptable FTP client such as [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html)

e.g. WIndows

```
for %s in (example.com example.org example.net) do ncftpput %s docroot misima.jpg
```

Similar for Linux bash